# How can you encode a string using a number cipher (A = 1, B = 2, etc)

Tags: c++

In my second year of University and to be honest I haven't been taught in the most effective way possible. My task is to take a word from a vector list, convert it using a substitute cipher, so A = 1, B = 2, and so on and then return that newly substituted word back for display and the user has to guess what the word might be. I'm struggling to understand how to create a cipher, please could someone check over the code and maybe give any comments on how to improve it perhaps? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GetCategory(int categoryChoice)
{
    ifstream ifsTeams("Premier League Teams.txt"); //gets an input file stream to read file
    vector<string> linesOne;        //vector to store each line from the file
    string tempLine;                //temp storage for each line
    while (getline(ifsTeams, tempLine)) //getline returns false at end of file
    {
        linesOne.push_back(tempLine);
    }

    ifstream ifsCharacters("Hobbit Characters.txt"); //gets an input file stream to read file
    vector<string> linesTwo;        //vector to store each line from the file
    string tempLineTwo;             //temp storage for each line
    while (getline(ifsCharacters, tempLineTwo)) //getline returns false at end of file
    {
        linesTwo.push_back(tempLineTwo);
    }

    ifstream ifsCountries("South American Countries.txt"); //gets an input file stream to read file
    vector<string> linesThree;      //vector to store each line from the file
    string tempLineThree;               //temp storage for each line
    while (getline(ifsCountries, tempLineThree))    //getline returns false at end of file
    {
        linesThree.push_back(tempLineThree);
    }

    if (categoryChoice == 1)
    {
        return linesOne;
    }
    else if (categoryChoice == 2)
    {
        return linesTwo;
    }
    else if (categoryChoice == 3)
    {
        return linesThree;
    }
}

void Substitute(string answer)
{
    
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    int categoryNum = (rand() % 3) + 1;     //Random number for choosing one of the categories

    vector<string> category = GetCategory(categoryNum);     //Stores the return of one of the categories' vector list
    int listSize = (int)category.size();
    int answerChoice = (rand() % listSize) + 1;

    string answer = category[answerChoice];
    Substitute(answer);
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One simple improvement would be to not read all three files when depending on the value of `categoryChoice` you only need one. Another improvement would be to put your file reading loop into a separate function so you don't have to repeat it three times. You could also pass the name of the file as a parameter into this function.

Comment: Your plain is a string but your cipher is numeric. Therefore `Substitute` should be returning a `vector<int>` for the encrypted word.

Comment: The code doesn't ensure the file was opened successfully nor does it close the files when done reading from them.

Comment: @john So would i only use ifstream once and depending on what number generates then read the file and store it as a vector? And if i put it into a loop won't it put all the contents into one variable or vector? And thank you so much for the reply as well

Comment: @sweenish i didn't realise you had to ensure the file opened correctly or close the file manually, i thought C++ did that automatically. I haven't been taught about the ifstream really so this was just self taught code.

Comment: @xChris18 -- Remove the input file and rerun your program.  Then you will see that you're responsible to check if the file opened successfully.

Comment: @xChris18 Not sure I understand your concern. Because you are only opening one file, instead of three, you only need one variable.

Comment: @john but it's not one file, i've got three separate files in the project that contain the 3 different contents that are stored as vectors

Comment: @xChris18 I know there are three files, but you can open open multiple files with one piece of code. But anyway in your case you only need to open one file. This is so obvious that you must be misunderstanding what I'm saying.

Comment: @xChris18 I'll add an asnwer so you can see exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: @john ah i understand now, i'm sorry for the incompetency with this language. I'm taking a game development course and learning C# and C++ and the syntax throws me off in C++, i find it much more difficult. Thank you so much for the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

If your mapping is linear then why not using the ascii value of your character as:

```
printf("%d", answer-'A');
```

You can use bounds if your cipher uses symbols that are non linearly mapped to ascii:

```
if(answer >= '0' and answer < '9') {
     ;
}
else if (answer >= 'A' and answer < 'Z')
...
```

I strongly reccommend to work with linux so that issuing the cmd 'ascii' in the shell gives you the table for instance, also all c/c++ libraries are part of the man command and 'man strtoul' gives you the manual for that library. These are details that when combined together put linux systems on another world when it comes to development/hacking.

Comment: Note that while you can work your entire career and never encounter one of the rare exceptions, not all system use ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetCategoryFile` is wasteful because it opens and reads all three files even though you only need to open one file. Here's one way to rewrite the function so it only opens one file.

```
vector<string> GetCategory(int categoryChoice)
{
    // choose the filename depending on categoryChoice
    const char* filename;
    if (categoryChoice == 1)
    {
        filename = "Premier League Teams.txt";
    }
    else if (categoryChoice == 2)
    {
        filename = "Hobbit Characters.txt";
    }
    else
    {
        filename = "South American Countries.txt";
    }
    ifstream ifs(filename); //gets an input file stream to read file
    vector<string> lines;        //vector to store each line from the file
    string tempLine;                //temp storage for each line
    while (getline(ifs, tempLine)) //getline returns false at end of file
    {
        lines.push_back(tempLine);
    }
    return lines;
}
```